# Getting OSError when vs code tries to install any packages

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code

I was trying to install a formatter for python in VS code and when the editor tries to install the formatter I get the following error:

```
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified: 'C:\\Python310\\Scripts\\black.exe' -> 'C:\\Python310\\Scripts\\black.exe.deleteme
```

The whole terminal session:

```
PS D:\playarea> & C:/Python310/python.exe -m pip install -U black
Collecting black
  Downloading black-21.12b0-py3-none-any.whl (156 kB)                               |████████████████████████████████| 156 kB 469 kB/s----------------------------                              Requirement already satisfied: platformdirs>=2 in c:\users\youse\appdata\roaming\python\python310\site-packages (from
 black) (2.4.0)
Collecting tomli<2.0.0,>=0.2.6
  Downloading tomli-1.2.2-py3-none-any.whl (12 kB)
Collecting pathspec<1,>=0.9.0
  Downloading pathspec-0.9.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (31 kB)
Collecting typing-extensions>=3.10.0.0
  Downloading typing_extensions-4.0.1-py3-none-any.whl (22 kB)
  Downloading click-8.0.3-py3-none-any.whl (97 kB)
gic
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified: 'C:\\Python310\\Scripts\\black.exe' -> 'C:\\Python310\\Scripts\\black.exe.deleteme'
```

Important Note: I should note that I was learning about virtual environments earlier that day and I played a lot with which python interpreter should vs code use, But, I can't understand where is the wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the `--user` parameter then try again.

```
C:/Python310/python.exe -m pip install -U black --user
```

By the way, **adding python to PATH** is easy for you to call `python.exe` that you can use `python -m pip` instead of using the complete path.

Here's a similar issue: [Error installing package with executable](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/9023), which verifies it's related to permission. Add User in `C:\Python310` folder security pannel with full access permission solves this problem.

Please have a try.

Comment: First of all thank you very much this solved my problem.

Comment: I also want to tell you that this command is generated by VS code and not by me. I was just hitting the shortcut "Shift+Alt+F" to format my python file and it suggested installing this formatter then this error happened

Comment: @yousefelsayed. Got your meaning and glad my answer helps you.